# Maximum of norm

Tags: matrices, optimization, normed-spaces

Given a matrix $A$ with $N$ rows and $d$ columns, I would like to prove (or disprove) the following. Let $q(f)=\|(\begin{pmatrix} f_1&0&0&\cdots&0\\0&f_2&0&\cdots&0\\0&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&0\\0&0&0&\cdots&f_N\end{pmatrix}A)\|_F^2 + \frac{1}{N}\|Af\|_2^2$ (where F stands for frobenious norm), then the maximum of $q$ on the unit cube $[0,1]^n$ is attained at $(1,1,\ldots,1)$. You may also assume that the columns of $A$ are in the unit ball.

Comment: What is he definition of trace of the rectangular matrix $diag(f_1\dots f_N)A$?